# Playing third voice in piano with far away notes

Tags: piano

I am playing the Promenade of Mussorgski from pictures at an exhibition. And I came across this: [image: third voice]

How can I play that? Up to now I just keep skipping the lower C on the treble key.

Comment: Huh, I'd personally play the full C-A-C chord there and then let go of either all of them or the bottom C when I play the F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the *sostenuto* pedal will hold CAC giving you chance to play the F after, without the CAC notes being cut short. There are players who can manage the stretch, but using the pedal makes sense. YOu could even use the damper pedal just for that section of the bar, or even half pedal.

Comment: Thank you Tim, I am going to use the pedal. I feel like playing the F on the treble key is easier using the left hand. Thanks!

Comment: Crossing hands has been the solution to many problems such as this. Looks pretty good too !